# Looping through a function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, api

I am struggling with figuring out the best way to loop through a function. The output of this API is a Graph Connection and I am a-little out of my element. I really need to obtain ID's from an api output and have them in a dict or some sort of form that I can pass to another API call.

**** It is important to note that the original output is a graph connection.... print(type(api_response) does show it as a list however, if I do a print(type(api_response[0])) it returns a

**This is the original output from the api call:**

[{'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '5c9941fcdd2eeb6a6787916e', 'type': 'user'}}, {'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '5cc9055fcc5781152ca6eeb8', 'type': 'user'}}, {'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '5d1cf102c94c052cf1bfb3cc', 'type': 'user'}}]

**This is the code that I have up to this point.....**

```
api_response = api_instance.graph_user_group_members_list(group_id, content_type, accept,limit=limit, skip=skip, x_org_id=x_org_id)


def extract_id(result):
    result = str(result).split(' ')
    for i, r in enumerate(result):
        if 'id' in r:
            id = (result[i+1].translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
            print( id )
            return id

extract_id(api_response)


def extract_id(result):
    result = str(result).split(' ')
    for i, r in enumerate(result):
        if 'id' in r:
            id = (result[i+8].translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
            print( id )
            return id

extract_id(api_response)

def extract_id(result):
    result = str(result).split(' ')
    for i, r in enumerate(result):
        if 'id' in r:
            id = (result[i+15].translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
            print( id )
            return id

extract_id(api_response)
```

I have been able to use a function to extract the ID's but I am doing so through a string. I am in need of a scalable solution that I can use to pass these ID's along to another API call.

I have tried to use a for loop but because it is 1 string and i+1 defines the id's position, it is redundant and just outputs 1 of the id's multiple times.

I am receiving the correct output using each of these functions however, it is not scalable..... and just is not a solution. Please help guide me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve the response as a string issue I would suggest using python's [builtin json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Specifically, the method `.loads()` can convert a string to a dict or list of dicts. From there you can iterate over the list or dict and check if the key is equal to `'id'`. Here's an example based on what you said the response would look like.

```py
import json

s = "[{'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '5c9941fcdd2eeb6a6787916e', 'type': 'user'}}, {'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '5cc9055fcc5781152ca6eeb8', 'type': 'user'}}, {'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '5d1cf102c94c052cf1bfb3cc', 'type': 'user'}}]"

# json uses double quotes and null; there is probably a better way to do this though
s = s.replace("\'", '\"').replace('None', 'null') 

response = json.loads(s)  # list of dicts

for d in response:
    for key, value in d['to'].items():
        if key == 'id':
            print(value)  # or whatever else you want to do

            # 5c9941fcdd2eeb6a6787916e
            # 5cc9055fcc5781152ca6eeb8
            # 5d1cf102c94c052cf1bfb3cc
```

Comment: I have tried to use json.loads before on this problem and just tried again. I get this error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: That might actually be great! What are the types of the contents of list? Dictionaries or strings? If they are dictionaries then you can skip straight to the for loop.

Comment: agreed but I get a non serializable error when I skip straight to the for loop. I thank you though as I took your recommendation of fixing the json sring prior to loading it into json.loads.